# My app doesn't open the correct activity - why so?

Tags: android

Good afternoon

I'm developing an Android App and i'm having some trouble with it.
I have many buttons it the app that are supposed to open activities. I don't want to have a lot of different onClick() methods so i'm trying to make one generic that can retrieve the correct activity to open depending on which button was clicked.

I came up with this code that works correctly:

```
public void displayActivity(View view) {

    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.secondActitityButton:
            myClass = SecondActivity.class;
            break;
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("Unknown Button");
    }

    Intent myIntent = new Intent (this, myClass);
    startActivity (myIntent);
}
```

But this still means that i need to have a lot of switch cases (one for each button...). So i tried another aproach using the "Content Description" of the button to store the class name. This is the code:

```
public void displayActivity(View view) {
    Class myClass;
    String className = (view.getContentDescription().toString().trim());
    try {
        myClass = Class.forName(className);
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        myClass = MainActivity.class;
    }

    Intent myIntent = new Intent (this, myClass);
    startActivity (myIntent);
}
```

The Content Description of the button was defined to "*SecondActivity.class*".

But now when i click the button it keeps sending me to the MainActivity.

I researched but just couldn't find the answer for this problem...

Can anybody help please?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Class#forName()` expects a *fully qualified name* of the desired class. So class name should be something like `the.complete.packagename.YourActivity`.

Please note that's not the intended usage of content description, see [Make apps more accessible](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/apps). You should consider another approach.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I put the fully qualified name of the activity and it worked. I know that the content description isn't for this. It was a "quick workaround" found by a newbie in app development. If the `onClick()` method accepted multiple arguments this problem would be fixed in a simple way. But it only must have an argument of type `View`. Should i use the `Tag` attribute instead?